# Created a MVC app, turned on Google Login.. want to strip out the local Registration stuff using ApplicationDbContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, google-authentication

Created a MVC app, in vs2013, following this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Turned on Google Login.. 
Got the app SSOing with Google login (so we can use Google Edu)
Now want to strip out the local Registration stuff using ApplicationDbContext

We have our own local user stuff in our DB, from our legacy code, I just want the Google login stuff to work like the "ad" login stuff I'm replacing...

Can I do this? What is the best approach? are there any walkthrough/working example of this?

Basically after I login with Google the first time I want the skip the whole registration in the local db in app_data step.. no registration, no local db.

If I can't just scrape it out or turn it off, how can I connect it up to a Sybase 12 db via the DDtek driver, and create the local tables (letting C# do it, entity first is against our policies)